# Heroku Custom Domain Not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, dns

What is the correct way to connect a Heroku app with a custom domain?

This is how I did it in the past:

1. Point Godaddy's DNS to heroku's provided target (example:
   https://peaceful-escarpment-22825.herokuapp.com)
2. Turn on domain forwarding on the domain
3. Add domain to Heroku in the settings

For some reason now my provided target from Heroku is like this: mycustomdomain.com.herokudns.com. When I add that DNS to GoDaddy I get a There's nothing here, yet. page.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I kept skipping this step because the custom domain already showed up in my Heroku app. Ran this and it started working.

```
Heroku domains:add www.yourwebsite.com --app <app name>
```

Bonus: Want every page to be secure SSL? Use this awesome NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/force-ssl-heroku

---

**Update 2021: If you get a `sni_endpoint`* error please refer here: [Heroku Custom Domain: sni_endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70252737/heroku-custom-domain-sni-endpoint)*

Comment: @Justin in console either on your machine or at heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication

Comment: you have to add www to the custom domain when adding it:

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me, but I had to include `--app <app name>` at end of the command. Like this:

```
heroku domains:add www.yourwebsite.com --app <app name>
```

For the app name, it is the app name you used when creating the app in Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

FIXED!! After struggling for a long time setting up my www domain with my Heroku app, I had to point the domain to Cloudflare then set it up as follows:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6CJc.png .
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8PSQ.png .
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB0DI.png .

Then everything just works perfectly both NON-WWW and WWW domains.

I did not need to do any URL forwarding as see bellow

[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgMit.png .

Answer (score 0):

```
Heroku domains:add www.yourwebsite.com --app <app name>
```

This is the best way to do it as it needs to know which specific app to point to.