# Heroku Custom Domain Not Found (404)

Tags: heroku, dns, cname

I want an application hosted one heroku to be reachable through the `api` subdomain.
The issue is that when i reach the website, I get a [Not Found error message](https://api.stickyhabits.app/). Calling the url has no impact on the logs so I know the application is not reached.

By reading other issues on stack overflow, I can see that [many people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796355/heroku-custom-domain-not-working) did not properly add the custom subdomain but I don't think that's the issue here. I created the subdomain through heroku's web interface.

If I run this in my terminal

```sh
$ heroku domains -a myapp
```

I get the following result

```
=== stickyhabitsapi Heroku Domain
myapp.herokuapp.com

=== stickyhabitsapi Custom Domains
Domain Name          DNS Record Type DNS Target
api.stickyhabits.app CNAME           mydnstarget
```

The DNS is managed by netlify. With their interface, I created a CNAME pointing to the DNS target supplied by heroku. Any Idea what might have gone wrong ?