# Heroku Custom Domain: sni_endpoint?

Tags: heroku

When adding a custom domain to my Heroku app I ran into the error below. Turns out Heroku has added a new requirement: `Beginning November 1, 2021, this new parameter will be required: sni_endpoint`

```
heroku domains:add www.mywebsite.com 
Adding www.mywebsite.com to ⬢ mywebiste... done

     ›   Error: Require params: sni_endpoint.
     ›   Error ID: invalid_params
```

Can someone tell me the new syntax to use instead of `heroku domains:add www.mywebsite.com`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried on my end after running a `heroku update` command and it enqueued the new domain correctly.

I guess your Heroku CLI toolbelt is out of date and not sending the newly required `sni_endpoint` to their API. After all, it's just a CLI wrapper for their API.

Comment: Thanks! Can you share the syntax you used?

Comment: Of course!
So I ran
`heroku update`

and then a basic
`heroku domains:add my-domain.com --app my-heroku-app-name`

Comment: Thanks for the help Stan!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it from the CLI, but in the meantime you can log in to the dashboard, go to Settings, then scroll down to Domains and add it there. I just did it that way and it works.